# single client_id vs. user authorization for showing multiple instagram feeds on a website

Tags: api, instagram

I'm developing of a community website that features about 500 user profiles. We now want to add the option to show the users' Instagram feed on their profile (with their consent). Going through the instagram API documentation some questions arose concerning the right approach about permissions and the review process.

Can anyone clarify if the following is a working approach and a valid use case regarding instagram's policy: Creating one client ID / access token for the website that is used to communicate serverside with the Instagram API, using the public_content permission to query the members' timeline. Server side caching would ensure that the rate limits are respected.

Since we need read-only access to public content only we would like to avoid managing authorization of every single member.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent API changes Instagram removed the ability to use the client_id for requests and now an access_toek obtained by authorising and Instagram account is required for everything

You could make an account for your website, authorize it and use its access_token, but it will need to apply for the public_content permission and I don't thin Instagram will like this use case. Also with 500 accounts you may hit your Ali request limit.

The better option is to require uses to authorise their Instagram account if they want their recent posts on their profile and use their token to get their recent posts. This way you don't need the public_content permission